# Filter jQuery Datatable with Select Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple table that I use with DataTables:

```
<table class="table table-hover nowrap data-table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th style="displaynone;">Type</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>12.12.2019</td>
      <td style="displaynone;">computer</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Above the table I have a select with all types that exist.
Now I want to use jQuery to filter the table by the corresponding value in the change event:

```
$('#types').change(function(){
  const selVal = $( "#types option:selected" ).text();

//...do the filtering
```

But I have no idea how to implement this. The table is filled with data by PHP and not via an Ajax call.

I have outsourced the creation of the DataTables in a JS Function:

```
var dataTable;
var dataTables = [];
function make_dataTable() {
    jQuery('table.data-table').each(function() {
            dataTable = jQuery(this).DataTable({
                responsive: false,
                pageLength: 25,
                autoWidth: true,
                lengthChange: false,
                language: { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json" }
            });
            if (jQuery('table.data-table').length > 0) {
                new jQuery.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader( dataTable );
            }
            dataTables.push(dataTable);
        });
}

function dataTables_destroy() {
    for (var i=0; i<dataTables.length; i++) {
        dataTables[i].destroy();
    }
}

make_dataTable();
```

Edit:

I cloud fix it.
Only a little thinking and RTFM.

```
var NRequest = $('#newRequest').DataTable({
  responsive: false,
  pageLength: 25,
  autoWidth: true,
  colReorder: true,
  lengthChange: false,
  columnDefs: [
    { type: "de_date", targets: 0 }
  ],
  order: [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  language: { "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json" }
});

$('#requestTypeNew').on('change', function(){
  const selVal = $( "#requestTypeNew" ).val();
  NRequest.column(1).search( selVal ).draw();
});
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a look at [official tutorials](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/examples/initialisation/col_filter.html) in that regard?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Individual column searching filter for js sourced data using DataTable.js with filter at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56363379/individual-column-searching-filter-for-js-sourced-data-using-datatable-js-with-f)

Comment: No, I tried it like this: https://pastebin.com/CphBDE78 but nothing happens, no errors but no sort too.

Comment: Thanks for the "kick" in the butt. I could fix it. I will edit my question and post the answer. Thank you again.

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem. Instead of adding the answer as part of your question, you should post the answer as a separate answer (in the "Your Answer" section). More generally, you are always welcome  to answer your own questions - and you can even accept your own answer, if you wish.